# Firestore: Pagination with Cursor

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to paginate data with Firestore, and would be ordering data on columns where duplicates are expected, if the pagination happens to be among those values its expected that it won't work correctly.

I can work around this issue by using StartAfter based on Document ID which will be always be unique.

1. One way I can accomplish this is passing id of the last document to  server side rest api request. This would require two steps, i.e. to fetch the DocumentSnapshot using the DocumentId and constructing the query based on it

   var lastSnapshot = fetchSnapshot(id);
   citiesRef.OrderBy("Population").StartAfter(lastSnapshot);
2. Other approach is to persist the DocumentId in the document while creation.This would require two steps each time when the document is created, one to create and the other to update immediately with Id generated (As I don't see a way to persist DocumentId during creation itself)

   citiesRef.OrderBy("Population").StartAfter(lastId);

Which one of these is a good approach to follow, either to fetch DocumentSnapshot and not to persist id into the document, or perform two operations by persisting the DocumentId in the first place and using it as key for StartAfter.

Comment: Why are you not using the solution that is explained in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query)?

Comment: as per the doc, you can only reduce ambiguity, not eliminate it unless the column ordering is based on unique values: When using a cursor based on a field value (not a DocumentSnapshot), you can make the cursor position more precise by adding additional fields. This is particularly useful if your data set includes multiple documents that all have the same value for your cursor field, making the cursor's position ambiguous. You can add additional field values to your cursor to further specify the start or end point and reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to go with Option 1, instead of persisting Document ID in the Document itself as in Option 2.

Comment: In my case, with option 1 getting duplicate data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805471/google-firestore-sending-duplicates-while-pagination-through-nodejs